# Setting corner radius as a negative value to achieve concave corners

Tags: swift, calayer

I use this code to round my corners of `UIView`:

```
extension UIView {

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

then I used `view.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: view.frame.width/3)`

Now this rounds the corners to be convex, and I want the opposite. Meaning the top corners will stay in the same points, but the line between them is rounded towards the inside of the view.
I tried achieving this by calling the above function with a negative value, but this resulted with just nothing happening.

I added a picture that calrifies my goal.
How could I achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to create your own `UIBezierPath`.  For the concave ends, `addQuadCurve(to:controlPoint:)` comes in handy.

Here I'm using the parameter `depth` to control the amount of curve:

```
extension UIView {

    func concaveEnds(depth: CGFloat) {
        let width = self.bounds.width
        let height = self.bounds.height

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width - height * depth, y: height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.zero, controlPoint: CGPoint(x: height * depth, y: height / 2))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

Demo in a Playground:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 100))
view.backgroundColor = .red

view.concaveEnds(depth: 0.4)
```

[image: Demo in Playground]
[image: Demo with less curve]

Comment: amazing perfect answer. Thanks for the efforts!

Comment: @vacawama what about if i wanted from the left side only ?

Comment: @AaoIi, replace the first `path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width - height * depth, y: height / 2))` with `path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))`

Comment: @vacawama How can I make concave face to bottom?